# Remove <br> tag from HTML to get string to print on one line with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The code is something like:

```
<a>
    Some text
    <br>
    Some more text
</a>
```

Using BeautifulSoup I'm trying to get the text inside the  tag to print on one line using a.text

The output I want is:
"Some text Some more text"

But the output I get is:
"Some text
Some more text"

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the SimplifiedDoc Library.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<a>
    Some text
    <br>
    Some more text
</a>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.a.text)
```

Result:

```
Some text Some more text
```

Comment: It might not be the best solution but I put the result in a list which let me get rid of the '\n' element by using `result = result.replace('\n',' ')`. Then I just printed the new result out

Comment: Of course, you can solve the problem in this way. What's important is that it can meet your needs.